# How to build an inflation term structure in QuantLib?

Tags: quantlib

This is what I've got, but I'm getting weird results. Can you spot an error?:

```
#Zero Coupon Inflation Indexed Swap Data
zciisData = [(ql.Date(18,4,2020), 1.9948999881744385),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2021), 1.9567999839782715),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2022), 1.9566999673843384),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2023), 1.9639999866485596),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2024), 2.017400026321411),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2025), 2.0074000358581543),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2026), 2.0297999382019043),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2027), 2.05430006980896),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2028), 2.0873000621795654),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2029), 2.1166999340057373),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2031), 2.152100086212158),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2034), 2.18179988861084),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2039), 2.190999984741211),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2044), 2.2016000747680664),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2049), 2.193000078201294)]

def build_inflation_term_structure(calendar, observationDate):
    dayCounter = ql.ActualActual()
    yTS = build_yield_curve()

    lag = 3

    fixing_date = calendar.advance(observationDate,-lag, ql.Months)
    convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing

    cpiTS = ql.RelinkableZeroInflationTermStructureHandle()
    inflationIndex = ql.USCPI(False, cpiTS)

    #last observed CPI level
    fixing_rate = 252.0
    baseZeroRate = 1.8


    inflationIndex.addFixing(fixing_date, fixing_rate)


    observationLag = ql.Period(lag, ql.Months)

    zeroSwapHelpers = []
    for date,rate in zciisData:
        nextZeroSwapHelper = ql.ZeroCouponInflationSwapHelper(rate/100,observationLag,date,calendar,
                                                              convention,dayCounter,inflationIndex)
        zeroSwapHelpers = zeroSwapHelpers + [nextZeroSwapHelper]

    # the derived inflation curve
    derived_inflation_curve = ql.PiecewiseZeroInflation(observationDate, calendar, dayCounter, observationLag,
                                                        inflationIndex.frequency(), inflationIndex.interpolated(),
                                                        baseZeroRate, yTS, zeroSwapHelpers,
                                                        1.0e-12, ql.Linear())
    cpiTS.linkTo(derived_inflation_curve)
    return inflationIndex, derived_inflation_curve, cpiTS, yTS

observation_date = ql.Date(17, 4, 2019)
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
inflationIndex, derived_inflation_curve, cpiTS, yTS = build_inflation_term_structure(calendar, observation_date)
```

If I plot the inflationIndex zero rates, I get this:
[image]

Comment: hi Lay did you get anywhere with this? I am new to QL and trying to get my head around inflation curve bootstrapping.

Comment: @PrasKam unfortunately no

Comment: might be worth sending this to the QuantLib mailing list and see if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I've now been checking the same problem and first of all I don't think you need that function `ZeroCouponInflationSwapHelper` at all.

Just to let you know I've perfectly replicated OpenRiskEngine (ORE)'s inflation curve which itself is built on QuantLib and the idea is quite simple.

1. compute base value I(0) which is the lagged CPI (this is supposedly your value `252.0`),
2. compute CPI(*t*)=I(*T*)=I(0)*(1+quote)^*T*, where *T* = ZCIS expiry date, *t* is *T* - 3M

I'm not sure where you took I(0) from, but since a lag is present the I(0) is *not* the latest available CPI value. Instead I(0)=I(2019-04-17) is interpolated value of CPI(2019-01) and CPI(2019-02).

Also to build the CPI curve you don't need any interest rate yield curve at all because the ZCIS pays at maturity *T* a single cash flow: 'floating' (I(*T*)/I(0)-1) for 'fixed' (1+quote)^*T*-1 cash flows. If you equate these, you can back out the 'fair' I(*T*) which I used above.

Assuming your value I(0)=252.0 is correct, your CPI curve would look like this:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

fixing_rate      = 252.0
observation_date = ql.Date(17, 4, 2019)

zciisData = [(ql.Date(18,4,2020), 1.9948999881744385),
              (ql.Date(18,4,2021), 1.9567999839782715),
              (ql.Date(18,4,2022), 1.9566999673843384),
              (ql.Date(18,4,2023), 1.9639999866485596),
               (ql.Date(18,4,2024), 2.017400026321411),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2025), 2.0074000358581543),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2026), 2.0297999382019043),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2027), 2.05430006980896),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2028), 2.0873000621795654),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2029), 2.1166999340057373),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2031), 2.152100086212158),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2034), 2.18179988861084),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2039), 2.190999984741211),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2044), 2.2016000747680664),
                 (ql.Date(18,4,2049), 2.193000078201294)]

fixing_dates = []
CPI_computed = []
for tenor, quote in zciisData:
    fixing_dates.append(tenor - ql.Period('3M')) # this is 'fixing date' t
    pay_date = ql.ActualActual().yearFraction(observation_date, tenor) # this is year fraction of 'pay date' T
    CPI_computed.append(fixing_rate * (1+quote/100)**(pay_date))

results = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.Series(fixing_dates).apply(ql.Date.to_date), 'CPI':CPI_computed})
display(results)
results.set_index('date')['CPI'].plot();
```

[image]